# get rid of uninstalled app from updates in app store

Tags: mac-appstore, macos

In the app store, I have a update for an app called "[Nepenthes](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/nepenthes/id764623073?mt=12)", by Wei Li, which claims to be "for enterprise solution".

However, I've never installed an app by that name, and I can't find it anywhere on the drive.

How do I get rid of it - in two parts:

1) How do I get rid of the update listing in the app store? (I've tried removing ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.commerce/updates.plist and rebooting.

2) How do I make sure it is **not** installed? (other than not finding it on the hard drive)

Thanks,
Russ

Comment: Check for it in your Purchases list. If it's there it will say 'Download' if you 'purchased' it but either didn't install or discarded it. It will say 'Open' if it's installed.

Comment: I have Nepenthes too, what gives?

Answer (score 1):

Turned out this is renamed SQLiteClient.app

[image]